# Store Paypal Payments Pro account information outside of Web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, paypal

I am using [the .NET SDK for Paypal Payments Pro](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index). The sample application stores the API account credentials in the website's `Web.config` file. I'd like to be able to pull these credentials from the database, instead.

Some searching turned up this entry, which asks the same question: [Edit Settings in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985068/edit-settings-in-web-config). Unfortunately, the accepted answer didn't address how to store the credentials elsewhere; instead, it showed how to programmatically modify the `Web.config` file.

Is there any way to specify the Paypal Payments Pro API credentials programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, PayPal .NET SDKs are designed to pick the API account credentials only from the configuration file. Perhaps, future version will support dynamic authentication.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UDPATE**

You should be able to re-write the `ConfigManager` class and the `SDKConfigHandler` class to retrieve the values from a database (not `web.config`).

`ConfigManager` retrieves the data and uses the `SDKConfigHandler` class to structure the data so other methods and classes can use it.

You'll find both classes in `\PayPal_Merchant_SDK\Manager\`.

**ORIGINAL**
After reviewing [the SDK](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/Payflow_dotNET_v4.50RC.zip), it looks like all you have to do is specify the credentials with a new `UserInfo` object:

```
UserInfo User = new UserInfo("<user>", "<vendor>", "<partner>", "<password>");
```

You just need to populate `user`, `vendor`, `partner`, and `password`, so I see no reason why you cannot store those in a database and retrieve them as necessary.

The `UserInfo` object is passed as a parameter to the `SaleTransaction` constructor.

```
SaleTransaction Trans = new SaleTransaction(User, Connection, Inv, Card, RequestID);
```

It would seem that as long as you re-instantiate both the `UserInfo` object and the the `SaleTransaction` object after switching credentials, you should be fine.

The `PayflowUtility.AppSettings` seems to merely be a helper method for retrieving the values from `app.config`. From Line 87 of `DOSaleComplete.cs`:

```
Should you choose to store the login information (Vendor, User, Partner and Password) in
app.config, you can retrieve the data using PayflowUtility.AppSettings. 

For Example:

    App.Config Entry: <add key="PayflowPartner" value="PayPal"/>

    String mUser = PayflowUtility.AppSettings("PayflowUser"); 
    String mVendor = PayflowUtility.AppSettings("PayflowVendor");
    String mPartner = PayflowUtility.AppSettings("PayflowPartner");
    String mPassword = PayflowUtility.AppSettings("PayflowPassword");

    UserInfo User = new UserInfo (mUser, mVendor, mPartner, mPassword);
```

Comment: the SDK you referenced is the PayFlow SDK, I am trying to use the Paypal SDK - https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index - in particular the DirectPayment feature. I just searched the Paypal SDK API and there are no `SaleTransaction` or `UserInfo` classes.

Comment: @ScottMitchell: The link I posted is for the SDK of "PayPal Payments Pro (Payflow Edition)". It's the only link at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index I saw for "PayPal Payments Pro". Please post a direct link to the .zip you are using, or to the documentation you are using.

Comment: I did post a link to the SDK page in my question - https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index - but you're right, I didn't post a link to the actual ZIP file. Here is the one I am using - https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/merchant-dotnet-1.2.95.zip. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Someone's forked the project at github to use a hashtable instead of web.config
https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/pull/2

> This changeset allows for passing the PayPal configuration in
>   hashtable form to the PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService. This grants
>   the ability to store config data in an external config file or
>   database rather than forcing the use of an app/web.config file. This
>   is especially useful for shared class libraries that perform PayPal
>   SDK operations which are utilized by multiple calling applications;
>   also the ability to store a large number of accounts in a database
>   rather than a config file is advantageous. Backwards compatibility for
>   existing app/web.config configurations is supported.