# Use PayPal .NET SDK without ConfigurationManager and Web.config

Tags: .net, paypal, configuration-files

We are integrating PayPal with our web app, hosted in Azure. Following best practice recommendations, we have been putting config values in the CSCFG file rather than web.config or app.config, but it looks like the PayPal .NET SDK only supports authentication via web.config/app.config values.

Does anyone know of a way to set the authentication values in C# code? This would allow us to continue to use the CSCFG file as the repository of all our config values.

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with this myself.  You can look at the code, but who wants to.  Check out the following article:

[Store Paypal Payments Pro account information outside of Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095904/store-paypal-payments-pro-account-information-outside-of-web-config)